Requesting mandatory travelers information in WooCommerce checkout and display it in thankyou, emails and admin order
I am creating a website to sell tickets for trips. For each ticket you book, I am asking a few questions for each passenger.
I wrote a code in 6 sections :

Create the fields for each ticket bought
Save fields values
Fields validation
Display infos to Thankyou screen
Display infos on emails
Display infos in admin edit order pages

/*1 - Create the fields for each ticket bought*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'person_details' );
function person_details($checkout) {
    global $woocommerce;
$count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
$i = 1;
       for($k=1; $k<= $count; $k++) {
        
           print ('<h3>Please enter details of attendee '.$i.'</h3>');
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_full_name'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Full name'),
            'placeholder'   => __('Enter full name'),
            'required'=> true
            ),
            $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_full_name'.$i ));
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
           
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_gender'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'radio',
            'class'         => array('form-row-first validate-required woocommerce-validated'),
            'label'         => __('Veuillez indiquer votre sexe ?' ),
            'options' => array(  
                    'Homme' => __('Homme','plugin-costarica' ),
                    'Femme' => __('Femme','plugin-costarica' ),
                    'Autre' => __('Autre','plugin-costarica' ),
        ),
            'required'=> true
            ),
            $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_gender'.$i ));
           
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_partage'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'radio',
            'class'         => array('form-row-last validate-required woocommerce-validated'),
            'label'         => __('Êtes-vous d\'accord pour partager votre chambre avec un ou plusieurs autres voyageurs ?' ),
            'options' => array(  
                    'Oui' => __('Oui','plugin-costarica' ),
                    'Non' => __('Non','plugin-costarica' ),
        ),
            'required'=> true
            ),
            $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_partage'.$i ));
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
           
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_infos'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'textarea',
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Préférences alimentaires et informations médicales','plugin-costarica' ),
            'placeholder'   => __('Merci d\'indiquer aussi précisément que possible votre régime alimentaire et toute information, problèmes et antécédents médicaux qui vous paraissent pertinents pour ce voyage.','plugin-costarica'  ),
            'required'=> true
            ),
            $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_infos'.$i ));
           
$i++;}
}

/*2 - Save value of fields */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'customise_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
function customise_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id)
{
    global $woocommerce;
$count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
$i = 1;
       for($k=1; $k<= $count; $k++) {
        
    if (!empty($_POST['cstm_full_name'.$i])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'Nom'.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST['cstm_full_name'.$i]));
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['cstm_gender'.$i])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'Gender'.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST['cstm_gender'.$i]));
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['cstm_partage'.$i])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'Partage chambre'.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST['cstm_partage'.$i]));
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['cstm_infos'.$i])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'Infos'.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST['cstm_infos'.$i]));
    }$i++;
}
}

//3 - Validation
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wholesale_option_validation' );
function wholesale_option_validation() {
        global $woocommerce;
        $count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
        $i = 1;
        for($k=1; $k<= $count; $k++) 
            {
            if ( empty($_POST['cstm_full_name'.$i]) OR empty($_POST['cstm_gender'.$i]) OR empty($_POST['cstm_partage'.$i]) OR empty($_POST['cstm_infos'.$i])) {
            wc_add_notice( __('Une ou plusieurs informations sur les voyageurs sont manquantes', 'plugin-costarica') );}
            $i++;
            }
    }

//4 - Adding infos to Thank you screen
function thankyou( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
    $i = 1;
    $message='';
    for($k=1; $k<= $count; $k++) 
        {   
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        
        $nom = $order->get_meta( 'Nom'.$i );
        $nom = esc_html($nom);
        
        $gender = $order->get_meta( 'Gender'.$i );
        $gender = esc_html($gender);    
        
        $partage = $order->get_meta( 'Partage chambre'.$i );
        $partage = esc_html($partage);
        
        $infos = $order->get_meta( 'Infos'.$i );
        $infos = esc_html($infos);      
        
        $message.= '<table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Nom du voyageur '.$i.'</td>
                    <th>'.$nom.'</td>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sexe</td>
                    <td>'.$gender.'</td>
                </tr>
                    <td>Partage de chambre</td>
                    <td>'.$partage.'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Infos additionnelles</td>
                    <td>'.$infos.'</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <br/>';
        
        $i++;
        }   echo $message;
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'message_concatenation', sanitize_text_field($message));
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'thankyou', 10, 2 );

//5 - Display infos on emails
function modif_email_commande_exempt_tva( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
        $message_email = $order->get_meta( 'message_concatenation' );
        if ( $email->id == 'customer_processing_order') 
            {echo $message_email;}}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'modif_email_commande_exempt_tva', 20, 4 );

//6 - Display in back-end
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    $message_backend = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'message_concatenation', true );
    if(!empty($message_backend)){echo $message_backend;}
}

1 and 2 are fine but I have many issues :

I can confirm the order even with my required fields being empty
No information appear on the email, the thank you or the back end

Can you please help me ? I tried to make my code as clear as possible :

There are some mistakes in your code, try the following revised code instead:
## 1 - Create the fields for each ticket bought
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'display_travelers_checkout_fields' );
function display_travelers_checkout_fields($checkout) {
    $count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ ) {
        
        echo '<h3>Please enter details of traveler '.$i.'</h3>';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_full_name'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'label'         => __('Nom complet', 'plugin-costarica'),
            'placeholder'   => __('Entrer votre nom complet', 'plugin-costarica'),
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'required'=> true
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_full_name'.$i ) );

        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
           
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_gender'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'radio',
            'label'         => __( 'Veuillez indiquer votre sexe ?', 'plugin-costarica' ),
            'class'         => array('form-row-first validate-required woocommerce-validated'),
            'required'      => true,
            'options'       => array(  
                'Homme' => __('Homme','plugin-costarica' ),
                'Femme' => __('Femme','plugin-costarica' ),
                'Autre' => __('Autre','plugin-costarica' ),
            ), 
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_gender'.$i ) );
           
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_share'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'radio',
            'class'         => array('form-row-last validate-required woocommerce-validated'),
            'label'         => __('Êtes-vous d\'accord pour partager votre chambre avec un ou plusieurs autres voyageurs ?', 'plugin-costarica' ),
            'required'      => true,
            'options'       => array(  
                'Oui' => __('Oui','plugin-costarica' ),
                'Non' => __('Non','plugin-costarica' ),
            ),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_share'.$i ) );

        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
           
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_infos'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'textarea',
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Préférences alimentaires et informations médicales', 'plugin-costarica' ),
            'placeholder'   => __('Merci d\'indiquer aussi précisément que possible votre régime alimentaire et toute information, problèmes et antécédents médicaux qui vous paraissent pertinents pour ce voyage.', 'plugin-costarica' ),
            'required'      => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_infos'.$i ) ); 
    }
}

// Utility function
function get_travelers_field_keys() {
    return array('cstm_full_name', 'cstm_gender', 'cstm_share', 'cstm_infos');
}

## 2) Fields Validation
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'travelers_checkout_fields_validation' );
function travelers_checkout_fields_validation() {
    $count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ ) {
        foreach ( get_travelers_field_keys() as $field_key ) {
            if ( isset($_POST[$field_key.$i]) && empty($_POST[$field_key.$i]) ) {
                wc_add_notice( __("Vous devez renseigner tous les champs du voyageur {$i}.", 'plugin-costarica'), 'error' );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

## 3) Save fields values
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_travelers_checkout_field_values');
function save_travelers_checkout_field_values( $order )
{
    $count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ ) {
        foreach ( get_travelers_field_keys() as $field_key ) {
            if ( isset($_POST[$field_key.$i]) && !empty($_POST[$field_key.$i]) ) {
                $order->update_meta_data( $field_key.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field_key.$i]) );
            }
        }
    }
    $order->update_meta_data( 'tickets_count', $count );
}

## 4) Format travelers data for display
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'save_formatted_travelers_data_for_display');
function save_formatted_travelers_data_for_display( $order )
{
    $count = $order->get_meta('tickets_count');
    $data  = array(); // Initializing

    for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ ) {
        $fname  = $order->get_meta('cstm_full_name'.$i);
        $gender = $order->get_meta('cstm_gender'.$i);
        $share  = $order->get_meta('cstm_share'.$i);
        $infos  = $order->get_meta('cstm_infos'.$i);

        $data[] = '<table>
            <tr>
                <th>'.__('Nom du voyageur').' '.$i.'</th>
                <td>'.$fname.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>'.__('Sexe').'</th>
                <td>'.$gender.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>'.__('Partage de chambre').'</th>
                <td>'.$share.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>'.__('Infos additionnelles').'</th>
                <td>'.$infos.'</td>
            </tr>
        </table>';
    }
    $order->update_meta_data( 'travelers_html', implode('<br>', $data) );
    $order->save();
}

## 5) Displaying travelers data to Thank you page
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'display_travelers_information_thankyou', 10 );
function display_travelers_information_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    echo $order->get_meta('travelers_html');
}

## 6) Display travelers data on emails
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'display_travelers_information_emails', 20, 4 );
function display_travelers_information_emails( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( in_array($email->id, ['new_order', 'customer_processing_order']) ) {
        echo '<h3>Details des voyageurs</h3>';
        echo $order->get_meta('travelers_html');
    }
}

## 7) Display travelers data in admin order
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'display_travelers_information_to_admin_order', 10, 1 );
function display_travelers_information_to_admin_order( $order ){
    echo $order->get_meta('travelers_html');
}

Code goes on functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Addition related to your comment:
The following will replace your first function.
To avoid having any checked value on the radio buttons fields, you need to add the following argument 'default'   => '', to the field array like:
## 1 - Create the fields for each ticket bought
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'display_travelers_checkout_fields' );
function display_travelers_checkout_fields($checkout) {
    $count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ ) {
        
        echo '<h3>Please enter details of traveler '.$i.'</h3>';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_full_name'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'label'         => __('Nom complet', 'plugin-costarica'),
            'placeholder'   => __('Entrer votre nom complet', 'plugin-costarica'),
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'required'=> true
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_full_name'.$i ) );

        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
           
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_gender'.$i, array(
            'type'      => 'radio',
            'label'     => __( 'Veuillez indiquer votre sexe ?', 'plugin-costarica' ),
            'class'     => array('form-row-first validate-required woocommerce-validated'),
            'required'  => true,
            'default'   => '',
            'options'   => array(  
                'Homme' => __('Homme','plugin-costarica' ),
                'Femme' => __('Femme','plugin-costarica' ),
                'Autre' => __('Autre','plugin-costarica' ),
            ),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_gender'.$i ) );
           
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_share'.$i, array(
            'type'      => 'radio',
            'class'     => array('form-row-last validate-required woocommerce-validated'),
            'label'     => __('Êtes-vous d\'accord pour partager votre chambre avec un ou plusieurs autres voyageurs ?', 'plugin-costarica' ),
            'required'  => true,
            'default'   => '',
            'options'   => array(  
                'Oui'       => __('Oui','plugin-costarica' ),
                'Non'       => __('Non','plugin-costarica' ),
            ),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_share'.$i ) );

        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
           
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_infos'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'textarea',
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __("Préférences alimentaires et informations médicales", 'plugin-costarica' ),
            'placeholder'   => __("Merci d'indiquer aussi précisément que possible votre régime alimentaire et toute information, problèmes et antécédents médicaux qui vous paraissent pertinents pour ce voyage.", 'plugin-costarica' ),
            'required'      => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_infos'.$i ) ); 
    }
}

Or you can replace the radio button fields with select fields like:
## 1 - Create the fields for each ticket bought
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'display_travelers_checkout_fields' );
function display_travelers_checkout_fields($checkout) {
    $count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ ) {
        
        echo '<h3>Please enter details of traveler '.$i.'</h3>';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_full_name'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'label'         => __('Nom complet', 'plugin-costarica'),
            'placeholder'   => __('Entrer votre nom complet', 'plugin-costarica'),
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'required'=> true
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_full_name'.$i ) );

        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
           
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_gender'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'label'         => __( 'Veuillez indiquer votre sexe ?', 'plugin-costarica' ),
            'class'         => array('form-row-first validate-required woocommerce-validated'),
            'required'      => true,
            'options'       => array(  
                ''      => __('Choisissez une option', 'plugin-costarica' ),
                'Homme' => __('Homme', 'plugin-costarica' ),
                'Femme' => __('Femme', 'plugin-costarica' ),
                'Autre' => __('Autre', 'plugin-costarica' ),
            ), 
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_gender'.$i ) );
           
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_share'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'class'         => array('form-row-last validate-required woocommerce-validated'),
            'label'         => __('Êtes-vous d\'accord pour partager votre chambre avec un ou plusieurs autres voyageurs ?', 'plugin-costarica' ),
            'required'      => true,
            'options'       => array(  
                ''    => __('Choisissez une option', 'plugin-costarica' ),
                'Oui' => __('Oui','plugin-costarica' ),
                'Non' => __('Non','plugin-costarica' ),
            ),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_share'.$i ) );

        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
           
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_infos'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'textarea',
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Préférences alimentaires et informations médicales', 'plugin-costarica' ),
            'placeholder'   => __('Merci d\'indiquer aussi précisément que possible votre régime alimentaire et toute information, problèmes et antécédents médicaux qui vous paraissent pertinents pour ce voyage.', 'plugin-costarica' ),
            'required'      => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_infos'.$i ) ); 
    }
}


This is brilliant - Thank you :) Just one issue - the two "ratio" fields are required but if you don't pick any option you can still submit the form and it works. However we do have "required=>true". Any idea how to fix this ?
